# Determine a lower sum estimate for the area between the curve $y = f(x)$ and the x-axis on the interval [0, 3] with 3 equal subdivisions.

Tags: calculus

Considering the function
$$f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x+2} $$

and given that $f(x)$ is a decreasing function on [0, 3], how do I determine a lower sum estimate for the area between the curve $y = f(x)$ and the $x$-axis on the interval [0, 3] with 3 equal subdivisions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of Lower Sum. Have you been given a partition? The simplest partition is $P=\{0,3\}$ and wrt to this, the estimate would e $3*f(3)$, since $f(3)$ is the minimum value taken by $f$ on the interval (using the information given about $g$ being decreasing).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT.** You want $3$ equal subdivisions, so clearly you divide $[0,3]$ into $0-1$, $1-2$, $2-3$. Now $f(x)$ is decreasing. So is it biggest at the left end of an interval, the right end, or somewhere in the middle? What values do you then use for $f(x)$ in your sum?